# Progressively rolling out new style guide per module in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, styling

Working on a large application. We have to roll out a new global style sheet on a page by page. module basis. Understandably this isn't the best approach. What is the best way to roll out a new global stylesheet per module? Have tried something like the below on each new page and referenced the old style sheet on older pages.

```
selector: "new-page",
templateUrl: "./new-page.component.html",
styleUrls: [
    '../../../node_modules/path-to-new-stylesheet/index.scss'
],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

However this approach causes a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content). Open to ideas.